# How can I add extra parameters to Edit method to pass them into a SqlCommand stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to use stored procedures with ASP.NET MVC methods, and I want to add some extra parameters to the Edit method because those parameters **cannot** be added to the model.

The question is: how can I extract that extra data from the view and pass it to the controller?

[My MVC Edit Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsZS7.png)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdCervezas,NombreCerveza,NombreBotella,GradoAlc,CantContenidoMl,Puntuacion,Expectativas,ComentariosCerveza,EstadoCerveza")] SistemaWeb_Proyecto.Areas.Cervezas.Models.Cervezas cervezas
                                                , Int32 idDistrib, Int32 idLocal, String codPertenencia, Decimal precio)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)_context.Database.GetDbConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

        connection.Open();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_Cervezas_InsertNewBeer";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre_Cerveza", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = cervezas.NombreCerveza;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre_Botella", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = cervezas.NombreBotella;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_TipoCerv", SqlDbType.Int).Value = null;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_Distrib", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idDistrib;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_Local", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idLocal;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo_Pertenencia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = codPertenencia;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cant_Contenido_ml", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cervezas.CantContenidoMl;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@grado_Alcohol", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = cervezas.GradoAlc;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@precio", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = precio;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@puntuacion", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = cervezas.Puntuacion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@expectativas", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = cervezas.Expectativas;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@comentariosCerveza", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = cervezas.ComentariosCerveza;

        int resultQuery = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (resultQuery == 1)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Success :D");
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Failed >:(");
        }

        _context.Add(cervezas);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(cervezas);
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Have you tried creating a CervezasViewModel POCO with all of the properties from your Cervezas domain model, plus the custom properties for your stored procedure parameters, and instructing your controller to use that?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks 4 the heads up man :D, so... can I use instead of `sp_` prefix a `My_SP_` prefix? If not well I tried at least changing it, 'cause on my last work we used to name SP's with that prefix.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ViewModel POCO? Well that's new, haven't heard of it like that. And I don't know if that's the best path to go on, 'cause I'd have to make an special ViewModel for each SP to work out, but correct me that If I'm wrong. Thanks for your answer

Comment: In MVC it's not uncommon to have Domain Models, View Models and Edit Models. The code generated by ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC just blends them into one layer by default. If you have custom stored procedures with extra parameters for each entity, though, maybe you need to use different tools.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Ohhh, okay I'll take ur word then, thanks :D.